# Write csv with dtype

Tags: python, pandas, dtype

I want to save large csv using pandas, however, when I save it, I'm losing dtype information, and therefore, when I reading it, I got the error: 
`DtypeWarning: Columns ... have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.`

Is these any elegant way to write and read csv, and preserve the dtypes?

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to save datatype metadata in a CSV file. However pandas `read_csv` can guess the type correctly most of the time. Post a sample data that does not work for you

Answer (score 0):

You can try import dataset this way:

```
dtypes = {
    'col_name1': 'type',
    'col_name2': 'type',
...
}
df = pd.read_csv('df_name.csv', sep = ';', encoding = 'cp1251', dtype = dtypes)
```

use dataset's sep and encoding

when you save, use:

```
df.to_csv('df_name.csv', index = False)
```